# BeautifulSoup get_text result as a string variable?

Tags: python, string, beautifulsoup

I need to collect text from a certain section of a wikipedia page, and put it into a single string variable. I can find the right text relatively easily, but I have no idea how to get it into a string variable.

My code so far:

```
with open('uottawa_wiki.html', 'rb') as infile:
    html_content = infile.read()
    
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')
soup = soup.body
           
campus_subsection = soup.find(id='Campus')

campus_subsection_siblings = campus_subsection.find_parent().find_next_siblings()

for sibling in campus_subsection_siblings:
    if sibling.name == 'p':
        print(sibling.get_text())
    else:
        break
```

And this is what it outputs, which is perfect:

> The university's main campus is situated within the neighbourhood of
> Sandy Hill (Côte-de-Sable). The main campus is bordered to the north
> by the ByWard Market district, to the east by Sandy Hill's residential
> area, and to the southwest by Nicholas Street, which runs adjacent to
> the Rideau Canal on the western half of the university. As of the
> 2010–2011 academic year, the main campus occupied 35.3 ha (87 acres),
> though the university owns and manages other properties throughout the
> city, raising the university's total extent to 42.5 ha (105
> acres).[32] The main campus moved two times before settling in its
> final location in 1856. When the institution was first founded, the
> campus was located next to the Notre-Dame Cathedral Basilica. With
> space a major issue in 1852, the campus moved to a location that is
> now across from the National Gallery of Canada. In 1856, the
> institution moved to its present location.[18]
>
> The buildings at the university vary in age from 100 Laurier (1893) to
> 120 University (Faculty of Social Sciences, 2012).[33] In 2011 the
> average age of buildings was 63.[32] In the 2011–2012 academic year,
> the university owned and managed 30 main buildings, 806 research
> laboratories, 301 teaching laboratories and 257 classrooms and seminar
> rooms.[4][32] The main campus is divided between its older Sandy Hill
> campus and its Lees campus, purchased in 2007. While Lees Campus is
> not adjacent to Sandy Hill, it is displayed as part of the main campus
> on school maps.[34] Lees campus, within walking distance of Sandy
> Hill, was originally a satellite campus owned by Algonquin
> College.[35]

However, I need all of this text, exactly as it is (line break and all) to be in a single string variable. I have NO CLUE how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Just append to a list in a loop and then `"\n".join()` it:

```
paragraphs = []
for sibling in campus_subsection_siblings:
    if sibling.name == 'p':
        paragraphs.append(sibling.get_text())
    else:
        break
full_text = "\n".join(paragraphs)
```

Comment: Brilliant, worked like a charm. Thanks! I tried something similar earlier but I was never taught how to use the join function so I'm just kind of fumbling around in the dark.